# Waiting until a os.system command finishes in my virtual machine (Windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, bash, virtual-machine, wait

I have encountered a problem with my python script. I am using python 3.6.2 I am using the os.system function to execute a bash command. The problem is the script launches the bash command and continues without waiting it to finish, knowing that the script acts correctly in my physical machine, it waits till the bash command is done then continues with the following instructions. This is my script:

```
import os
os.system("C:/Bash/bashCmd.sh")
print("ok")
```

I also tried subprocess.call, but it never waits in my vm.

My question is about the source of this issue, then if any suggestions to deal with it!

Comment: the code provided is not correct python, are hashtags as comment indicators missing?

Comment: I'm unsure of the significance of your mention of the virtual machine. Why is that relevant, and are you trying to run commands on it from another machine. Please give fuller information.

Comment: I did mention the virtual-machine because I have this problem in a virtual machine (win7), while there is no problem in my local machine (win10)

Comment: How have you installed Bash on the Win 7 virtual machine?

Comment: Make sure your bash scripts works properly in your vm by running it manually. It looks like `os.system` returns immediately because your script fails. You might have forgotten to install some dependencies for your script.

Comment: use the subprocess module https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: The bash command continues correctly till it finishes (about 30 seconds), but the print instruction is executed without waiting the bash command to be end

Comment: crux666 : I wrote in the question that I tried "subprocess.call", but nothing changed. that's why I have doubt about something related to the vm

Comment: What's in your Bash script? Are you running something in background? Because if you do, `os.system` call will return before the background task finishes.

Comment: `os.system` or `subprocess.call` with `shell=True` both execute the command line via `cmd /c`, and then wait for this CMD instance to exit. For a .sh file, CMD will end up calling `ShellExecuteEx`, which will probably call `CreateProcess` unless the .sh file association is peculiar. This should spawn a bash.exe child process and return a handle for it. CMD will wait on this handle. However, if the bash process spawns another bash process and then exits, then CMD will exit also. It can't wait on a grandchild process.